# How can I display this bunch of date filters in an intuitive way?

Tags: usability, forms, user-behavior

Our product is a CRM. The current page is a list of sales. Users can filter on a sales period to see how much sales they've had this week, last week etc.

I don't want to simply give them a From/To date picker because that will be tedious when they constantly has to change the date to see some common use cases.

The alternatives I have so far, and I'm not happy with either one of them:

**Inputs with radio buttons**
[image: Inputs with radio buttons]

**Radio buttons with common use cases**
[image: Radio buttons with common use cases]

**Links with common use cases:**
[image: Links with common use cases]

Any feedback or ideas? Couldn't find a standardised way of displaying this type of multi date selectors.

Comment: If you'd like to get more sophisticated, you could provide the users with variables that give them the values of the `currentMonth`, `currentQuarter`, and `currentYear`, then allow them to construct and save their own queries based on those values (similar to how [Microsoft's TFS queries](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/query-by-date-or-current-iteration) are constructed). It seems you also might be able to get some valuable feedback on presenting these options to your target users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend looking at Google Analytics Dashboard UI. I've included a screenshot of their dropdown menu. If you click 'custom' you are given a fully interactive calendar so any dates can be chosen. [image]